# Python 3.10 pyqt5 Label won't change 'setPixmap' when needed

Tags: python, set, match, qpixmap, pixmap

I'm currently running python 3.10 and within a match/case and having a weird outcome. Let me explain:

[Image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcduW.png)

```
class Test(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Test, self).__init__()

    # comboBox changes = image gets displayed on app 'WORKING'
    self.comboBoxIS.currentTextChanged.connect(partial(self.loadIsCombo, Testing=False))

    # Clicking 'Test' button to see if image is on the screen. At this point is on the app so technically it is.
    self.pushButtonIS_2.clicked.connect(partial(self.loadIsCombo, Testing=True))

def bufferIsCombo(self, Testing=False):
selectedItem = self.comboBoxIS.currentText()
bufferImg = 'resources/ui/buffering.png'
match selectedItem:
            case "Test 1":
                img = config['Test1']['Test1a']
                imgConf = config['Test1'].getfloat('Test1b')
                self.labelIS2.setText(str(imgConf))
                self.labelISConfig.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img))
                self.pushButtonIS_2.setEnabled(True) # Enable test button
                if Testing:
                    # Since the app contains the image i want to change it to another 'buffering'
                    self.labelISConfig.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(bufferImg))
                    # This setPixmap wont get applied until handler returns but by that time is to late.
                    # imageSearchTest() come back as false positibe because it was on the application
                    functions.imageSearchTest()
            case "Test 2":
                pass
            case "Test 20":
                pass
```

Everything works well until I run into the if Testing: statement. The new `self.labelISConfig.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(bufferImg))` will not change until after the function `imagesearchTest`.

The issue with that is I'm displaying that image on my application and running an image search function so it gives me a false positive because it finds the image on the application. To fix this I would like to change the label pixmap to a dif image `bufferImg` before the function starts running so I don't get that false positive.

Comment: When you say that you change to a different image before the function call, do you mean ```bufferImg```?

Comment: The image will not change until your event handler returns and the main loop gets a chance to process those messages.  You may need to use a slot to trigger a follow-up call to to the image search.

Comment: @ChaddRobertson Yes

Comment: @TimRoberts this whole code is already being processed by a slot. This match/case is inside a function named 'loadIsCombo' and is being accessed by two signals. **1.** _When the comboBox text changes_
```self.comboBoxIS.currentTextChanged.connect(partial(self.loadIsCombo, False))``` **2.** _When the button is pressed_ ```self.pushButtonIS_2.clicked.connect(partial(self.loadIsCombo, True))``` The reason I went this direction was so I wouldn't have to write this long match/case statement a second time just to run a function.

Comment: You don't have to do that.  If I understand you, all you want it to do the `setPixmap` but delay the `imageSearchText` call until that change has actually taken place.  So, all you need is a short callback that does nothing but call `functions.imageSearchTest()`, and trigger that as the last line of that clause.  Right?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes that's exactly what I need.  ```setPixmap``` to be applied then ```imageSearchTest()``` Everything I try seems to be a miss. I'm fairly new to coding but ill do some research on callbacks and try to implement it.

Comment: @TimRoberts okay well I unintentionally got it working. I was just playing around with the code and I added a ```QMessageBox.information(self.parent, "Test", "Test"``` and it worked. I ran the code line by line and I have no idea what is going on. All I can say is something in QMessageBox is updating my pixMap right after QMessageBox closes. This actually fixes my problem but I would still like to know what is going on in the backend.

Comment: It's exactly what I said.  The QMessageBox starts another message loop behind the scenes, and that lets your messages drain so that the pixmap can be updated.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thanks for taking the time and helping me out. I really appreciate it.